# Как одна программа может взять вывод другой программы?

Tags: python

Во-первых, программа 1 должна запустить программу 2.
Программа 2 посчитает некоторые математические действия, и ответ занесёт в переменную 1.
Затем, второе, программа 1 должна взять этот ответ и вставить её в свою переменную.

Условный пример:

Программа 1

```
q = open( 'program2.py', '[ ??? ]')

file = open( 'c', 'w')
file.write( 'что-то' )
file.close()
```

Программа 2

```
a = 2
b = 2
variable1 = a + b
```

(Знаю, было много подобных вопросов, но я не понял.)

Comment: А вы учебник хоть какой-то читать не пробовали?  Что такое функция -  знаете? Что такое "значение, возвращаемое функцией"? А что такое глобальная переменная? Или читать учебники - не наш путь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что вы хотите сделать, может выглядеть так:

**q1226821_1.py**

```
from q1226821_2 import _add                   # импорт функции `_add` из `q1226821_2.py`


fileName = 'test.txt'

variable = _add()                             # вызов функции `_add` на исполнение
                                              # результат ее работы будет в `variable`

with open(fileName, "w") as fileOutput:
    fileOutput.write(str(variable))
```

---

**q1226821_2.py**

```
def _add():              # это функция сложения двух переменных (int)
    a = 2
    b = 2
    variable1 = a + b
    return variable1     # return - возвращает резудьтат вычислений данной функции
```

Запускаем программу: `python q1226821_1.py`